# How to Validate Address Not Found Mails(Sent Mails) in SMTP(Java)

Tags: java, smtp, mime-message

```
@Override
public boolean sendOnboardingEmail(String emailTo, String onboardingDateTime, String userName) {
    Properties prop = System.getProperties();
    prop.put("mail.smtp.host", SMTP_SERVER);
    prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    prop.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", SMTP_SERVER);

    Session session = Session.getInstance(prop, null);
    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

    try {
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(EMAIL_FROM));
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(emailTo, false));
        msg.setSubject(EMAIL_SUBJECT);
        msg.setText(EMAIL_TEXT);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());

        SMTPTransport t = (SMTPTransport) session.getTransport("smtp");

        t.connect(SMTP_SERVER, EMAIL_FROM, PASSWORD);

        t.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
        t.close();

        return true;
    }  catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    
}
```

`I am using the above approach for sending emails,
I have to validate emails that are sent or not sent,
Valid emails have been sent but some emails have shown like the below in the inbox
i.e., address not found(The response was:
550 5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or unnecessary spaces. Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/?p=NoSuchUser y9-20020aa79e09000000b00687b0584e6bsor4586365pfq.1 - gsmtp)

can you suggest how to validate those mails (has sent or not)?`

Comment: Process the bounce emails you get, look for the error message and the original recipient, and remove these from your list. Make sure you email only people that want to receive email from you. Don't buy email lists.